# Magic transparent space between a-tags in html

Tags: html, css

So I was playing around with html, and I have made some links. By some magic power there is a magic space between the a-tags. I think it comes from the `display: inline-block` instruction, however the question is **how to handle this space in web design where every pixel counts**?

JsFiddle: 
[Go to JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9PrBL/)

Screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, start with embedding the a's in the li's, not the other way around.

And that magic space is not margin, it's the white space between your elements, which is mattering because you are using *inline*-block

Check out this question : [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: This markup works beautifully and it's done like this for a purpose. You didn't tell anything I have not included in my question. You also haven't answered the question in any way. Next time try to use the comment for such answer.

Comment: Well, if you know that the problem is caused by your white space in your markup, I thought it would be quite obvious that the first solution is to remove the white space, and the second to not use inline-block. Sorry for being unclear.

And the markup is invalid, regardless how beautiful you might find it.

Comment: Your issue is by the way handled in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Good job I give you the best answer but include the link in your answer for others. Thanks.